# c# WPF DatePicker to Label Binding, to get a persons age

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

My job is to bind a labels Content in XAML to a DatePicker, which is a persons birth date, to get their age. For example: Date picker: 2000.1.1 Label: 16. 
How do I do this?

**edit**

The label needs to change immediately when the DatePicker change.

Comment: Look at binding the label to the control via an element binding and add an IConvertor implementation tha t takes the date and returns the age.

Comment: You need to bind their birth date through a converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your label using an IValueConverter implementation such as the following:

```
class BirthdateToAgeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert
        (
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        string language)
    {
        var birthdate = ((DateTime) value).Date;
        var age = DateTime.Today.Year - birthdate.Year;

        if (birthdate > DateTime.Today.AddYears(-age))
        {
            age--;
        }
        return age;
    }

    public object ConvertBack
        (
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Edit:
In your XAML you need to define the binding path if you are binding directly to the DatePicker. You could also bind to SzuletesiDatum on your ViewModel.

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=dtPicker, Path=SelectedDate ,Converter={StaticResource DTKC}}" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="356,94,0,0" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top"/> 
<DatePicker x:Name="dtPicker" 
            SelectedDate="{Binding SzuletesiDatum}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="112,94,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: Thx, I copied it, but still i don't know what to write to the xaml.
 <Label    Content="{Binding ElementName=dtPicker ,Converter={StaticResource DTKC}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="356,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

        <DatePicker x:Name="dtPicker" SelectedDate="{Binding SzuletesiDatum}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

Doesn't work

Comment: Thank you, it is working, but now it throws an error with this: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " and underlines "Window" in the beginning of the xaml code. It only disapears when I delete this part: ,Converter={StaticResource DTKC}